# flake8 linting does not show up in problems tab or inside editor in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, flake8

I am working in a shared environment in a remote attached container (docker) for my work. We use flake8 linting (among others) with tox for checking the correctness before commits to source control can be made. Of course, we want to have continuous linting inside VSCode so we can see the errors/warnings while coding and don't have to clean up all the mistakes at the end.

I have tried a lot of combinations over the last couple of days to get the linting to work. Mypy linting works, pylint linting works, and flake8 actually is called and works, only nothing shows up in the editor.

settings.json conf:

```
{
    "python.linting.flake8Path": "flake8",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true, 
    "python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.F": "Error", 
    "python.linting.flake8CategorySeverity.E": "Error"
}
```

I have tried settings the full absolute path found with 'which flake8'. I have tried using the cornflakes flake8 extension. I have even tried overriding all tox.ini configurations under python.linting.flake8Args, and it works both in the terminal, and under the output tab.

On save output python tab shows:

```
> ~/repos/cloud-api2/venv/bin/python -m flake8 "--format='%(path)s:${yellow_bold}%(row)d${reset}:${green_bold}%(col)d${reset}: ${red_bold}%(code)s${reset} %(text)s" --ignore=ANN101,ANN002,ANN003,B009,D104,D401,N807,N813,W503 --max-complexity=12 --max-line-length=120 --v --format=%(row)d,%(col)d,%(code).1s,%(code)s:%(text)s ~/repos/cloud-api2/plugins/integration/src/UC_Integration/api/infrakit.py
cwd: ~/repos/cloud-api2
##########Linting Output - flake8##########
/srv/control/repos/cloud-api2/plugins/integration/src/UC_Integration/api/infrakit.py:141:1: W293 blank line contains whitespace
/srv/control/repos/cloud-api2/plugins/integration/src/UC_Integration/api/infrakit.py:142:1: E303 too many blank lines (3)
/srv/control/repos/cloud-api2/plugins/integration/src/UC_Integration/api/infrakit.py:153:12: W292 no newline at end of file
```

So it obviously works, it just refuses to show up in the editor in any capacity.

The problem must lie either in the environment, or as a result of developing through a remote container. I'm leaning towards the former, since the other linters works as expected. The flake8 configuration in the settings works just fine when creating a small test project locally, so I unfortunately can't provide a full minimal example where the problem is recreated. I have tried removing the tox.ini and setup.cfg files entirely (which is where flake8 is configured) and the problem persists, so I do not think that those are the cause. Obviously I have the needed python extension installed in the remote container as well as locally which provides flake8 linting.

Comment: I'd recommend removing flake8-colors, it's almost certainly the cause of your issue - the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation @AnthonySottile . I can see the flake8-colors was in fact part of the requirements, and the formatting included it. I have removed both, and the exact same situation described above persists. The command now is as follows: flake8 "--format=''%(path)s:%(row)d:%(col)d: %(code)s %(text)s'" --ignore=ANN101,ANN002,ANN003,B009,D104,D401,N807,N813,W503 --max-complexity=12 --max-line-length=120 --v --format=%(row)d,%(col)d,%(code).1s,%(code)s:%(text)s ~/repos/cloud-api2/plugins/integration/src/UC_Integration/api/infrakit.py

Comment: I wonder if it's mismatching the paths (I noticed full paths in the output and idk if vscode has a way to translate those back to your local filesystem paths)

Comment: Hmm yeah, that could be it. I have tried entering the full path name in args in VSCode under the filename= config (my thinking is that if I give the full path name to the file with the intentional errors it should be able to find it) but the problem is still the same. Do you think that means mismatching the paths is not the problem, or do you maybe have a recommendation as to a different way to to test the theory?

Comment: no idea, I only know the flake8 parts and those appear to be working correctly

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your attempt to solve it.